A block experiencing a constant force collides with a stationary block
If a constant force is exerted on a block 'A' on a frictionless surface and if it collides with a stationary block of a lesser mass on the same surface (let's call it block 'B') then upon the collision, would the reaction force be greater than the initial force exerted on block 'A' or would it be lesser?
I am asking because the net force exerted on block A at the instant of the collision would be lesser than the net force exerted upon it before the collision. Therefore, its acceleration at the instant of the collision would be lesser than its acceleration before the collision. But I am not sure as to whether its acceleration at the instant of the collision would be directed opposite to its initial motion or would it still be directed forwards.
In addition, would the blocks travel together as one mass after the collision or would block 'B' be pushed away from block 'A'?
Assume the scenario is perfectly elastic.

In a collision we are generally not able to know the forces. All we are interested in, or all that we know, is the impulse.
The impulse is the change in momentum, which is equal to the integral of the force over the duration of the collision. For the constant force, $\vec f_c$, that is $$\Delta \vec p_c=\int_a^b \vec f_c \ dt=\vec f_c \ (b-a)$$ where $a$ and $b$ are respectively the starting and ending time of the collision. If the collision is very brief, then $(b-a)$ is very close to zero and $\Delta p_c$ may be neglected.
This type of approximation is commonly made when analyzing automobile collisions. There is typically friction with the road. But during the brief time of the actual impact, the impulse due to the friction force is negligible. So friction is included in the analysis of the motion before and after, but not during the impact.

in collision problem we can obtain the velocities of block A and B after the collision and the impulse between the Blocks during the collision .
for your case with these equations
$$m_A\,(v_A-u_A)=-\lambda\\
m_B\,v_B=\lambda\\
v_B-v_A-\epsilon\,u_A=0$$
where $~v_A~,v_B~$ are the block velocities after the collision,
$~u_A~$ is the start velocity of block A,$~\lambda~$ is the impulse after the collision and $~\epsilon~$ is the coefficient of restoration $~(\epsilon=1~, \text{inelastic}~,\epsilon=0~, \text{elastic})~$
you obtain
$$\lambda=\frac{m_A\,m_B\,(\epsilon+1)}{m_A+m_B}\,u_A$$
the start impulse was $~\lambda_A=m_A\,u_A~$  thus
$$\frac{\lambda}{\lambda_A}= \frac{m_B\,(\epsilon+1)}{m_A+m_B}$$

would the blocks travel together as one mass after the collision or would block 'B' be pushed away from block 'A'?

with
$$ v_A=-\frac{\epsilon\,m_B-m_A}{m_A+m_B}\,u_A\\
v_B=\frac{(\epsilon+1)\,m_A}{m_A+m_B}\,u_A$$
thus:
the blocks travel together for elastic collision case
$~\epsilon=0~$ , for inelastic case $~\epsilon=1~$
block 'B' be pushed away from block 'A' only if
$~m_B >m_A~$
the velocity of the center of mass  (linear impulse is conserved):
$$v_{cm}=\frac{m_A\,v_A+m_B\,v_B}{m_A+m_B}=\frac{m_A}{m_A+m_B}\,u_A$$
